# What is thermal resistance of SMD7530 LED

Tags: resistance, datasheet, thermal

What is thermal resistance of SMD7530 similar to this photo (**Or typical LED in this type**):

[image]

With this datasheet:

[Datasheet for SMD7530](http://www.betlux.com/product/SMD_LED/BL-LS5730A1S1.PDF)

I cannot find any thermal resistance in it's datasheet.

Comment: I would contact the manufacturer for better information if I were you.

Comment: It's a crappy data sheet and that usually means a crappy supplier that neither knows the market nor cares.

Comment: But he might try at least.

Comment: Also you can find several LEDs from another manufacturers, but with same package, and compare their characteristics. If it's similar i think you can approximate it as 0.8*<typ.value>

Answer (score 2):

Since the maximum junction temperature is 120°C and the maximum current is 150mA, you can guess that the thermal resistance is such that 95°C of rise occurs at 0.465W given the typical forward voltage is 3.1V, so about 204K/W.

*However* that number is essentially useless since you don't know anything about the conditions under which that number is valid. It could be 20 x 20mm of aluminum core PCB, for example. If you assume that number and use FR-4 with modest amounts of thin copper, the LED life may be greatly foreshortened.